# How to insert year in string

Tags: php

I didn't write this PHP function, but I need to replace the static 2013 with PHP code for the current year:

```
<?php
 function footer_contents() {
  $block['disclaimer'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div class="footer-disclaimer">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );
  $block['disclaimer']['text'] = array(
   '#items' => array(
      l('&copy;2013 Company Name, 'http://www.companyname.com', array('html' => TRUE, 'attributes' => array('target' => '_blank'))),
    ),
    '#theme' => 'item_list',
  );
  return $block;
}
?>
```

I tried this:

```
l('&copy;'.echo date("Y").' Company Name, 'http://www.companyname.com', array('html' => TRUE, 'attributes' => array('target' => '_blank'))),
    ),
```

but that breaks the page. I'm a PHP newbie.

Comment: Is `l` a function ? Also just try it without the echo like this: `'&copy;'. date("Y").' Company Name,` (How to concatenate the right way see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Answer (score 1):

assuming l is a super short function name

```
l('&copy;'.date("Y").'Company Name', 'http://www.companyname.com', array('html' => TRUE, 'attributes' => array('target' => '_blank'))),
```

Comment: Awesome y'all, thanks! I knew it was something simple but no clue what.